# Unable to retrieve Data Oracle Fusion BI Publisher

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-bi, oracle-sql-data-modeler, oracle-fusion-apps

1.Main Code:

```
SELECT
  iodv.organization_id,
  iodv.organization_name,
  mil.SUBINVENTORY_CODE subinventory_name,
  mil.inventory_location_id locator_id,
  mil.segment11 || '.' || mil.segment12 || '.' || mil.segment13 locator_name
FROM
  inv_item_locations mil,
  inv_organization_definitions_v iodv
WHERE
  1 = 1
  and iodv.organization_id = mil.organization_id
  and iodv.Organization_Code = ':Organizations'
  and mil.SUBINVENTORY_CODE = ':p_Subinventories'
```

2. Parameter p_SubInventories:

```
select
distinct
iil.Subinventory_code
from 
inv_item_locations iil,
INV_ORG_PARAMETERS iop
where 
1=1
and iil.ORGANIZATION_ID=iop.ORGANIZATION_ID
and iop.ORGANIZATION_CODE= :Organizations
```

3. Parameter for Organizations:

```
select distinct organization_code from inv_org_parameters
```

Unable to retrieve data with the above query in Data Model @ Oracle BI Publisher......

Comment: I don't know Oracle BI Publisher, but - is it correct to enclose parameters into single qoutes? Shouldn't that be e.g. `and iodv.Organization_Code = :Organizations`?

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOIN here

```
SELECT
  iodv.organization_id,
  iodv.organization_name,
  mil.SUBINVENTORY_CODE subinventory_name,
  mil.inventory_location_id locator_id,
  mil.segment11 || '.' || mil.segment12 || '.' || mil.segment13 locator_name
FROM
  inv_item_locations mil
LEFT JOIN 
    inv_organization_definitions_v iodv
ON 
    iodv.organization_id = mil.organization_id
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND iodv.Organization_Code = ':Organizations'
  AND mil.SUBINVENTORY_CODE = ':p_Subinventories'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought the single apostrophe was problem, but maybe removing the inner join also helps.

It's worth noting the LEFT JOIN could be applied using using PL SQL Outer Join Operator (+). See adjustment to Ops main code below

```
SELECT
  iodv.organization_id,
  iodv.organization_name,
  mil.SUBINVENTORY_CODE subinventory_name,
  mil.inventory_location_id locator_id,
  mil.segment11 || '.' || mil.segment12 || '.' || mil.segment13 locator_name
FROM
  inv_item_locations mil,
  inv_organization_definitions_v iodv
WHERE
  1 = 1
  and iodv.organization_id  (+)  = mil.organization_id  ----
  and iodv.Organization_Code = ':Organizations'
  and mil.SUBINVENTORY_CODE = ':p_Subinventories'
```